# Tip calculator with different tips amount

Tags: python

Below is my code, I am trying to get tip amount with different tip option and tip amount should be a 2 decimal places but didn't get the result

```
bill_amount = float(input('How much is the bill? $'))
ten = float((bill_amount / 100) * 10)
fifteen = float((bill_amount / 100) * 15)
twenty = float((bill_amount / 100) * 20)
tip_option = input('Tip Options: ')
print('10% Tip amount is', {'ten.2f'})
print('15% Tip amount is', {'fifteen.2f'})
print('20% Tip amount is', {'twenty.2f'})
```

Comment: `{'ten.2f'}` is a set containing a single string. Were you trying to use `str.format` or `f"strings"`? I'd recommend reviewing the basics with one of https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: I think what you're trying to write is `f'{ten:.2f}'`. However, take the time to understand from tutorials what the meaning of this line of code is

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good case to use a multiline f-string:

```py
bill_amount = float(input('How much is the bill? $'))
ten = float((bill_amount / 100) * 10)
fifteen = float((bill_amount / 100) * 15)
twenty = float((bill_amount / 100) * 20)
tip_option = input(f'''Tip Options: 
10% Tip amount is', {ten:.2f}
15% Tip amount is', {fifteen:.2f}
20% Tip amount is', {twenty:.2f}
''')
```

The reason I suggest this approach is that you want to store the option chosen by the user in `tip_option` after being asked for the tip amount.

Answer (score 0):

In python3, you can format the string like:

```
print('10% Tip amount is {amount:.2f}'.format(amount = ten))
```

See this documentation page for `.format` for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your way to print data is a but outdated. In Python3 you can do

```
print('10% Tip amount is {:.2f}'.format(ten))                                                           
print('15% Tip amount is {:.2f}'.format(fifteen))                                                       
print('20% Tip amount is {:.2f}'.format(twenty))
```

for 2 decimal tips.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to the other answers:

```
print('10%% Tip amount is %.2f' % ten)
```

The double percent (`%%`) escapes the percentage sign from formatting. `ten`'s value replaces `.2f` and is formatted as a float to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to correct the format string. In line 6, I declared the variable. Look at lines 7, 8, and 9. I just added colons. I go with 49.00 and 15%. And the total will be $56.35

```
bill_amount = float(input('How much is the bill? $'))
ten = float((bill_amount / 100) * 10)
fifteen = float((bill_amount / 100) * 15)
twenty = float((bill_amount / 100) * 20)
tip_option = input('Tip Options: ')
total = bill_amount+fifteen 
print(f'10% Tip amount is {ten:.2f}')
print(f'15% Tip amount is {fifteen:.2f}')
print(f'20% Tip amount is {twenty:.2f}')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `f'15% Tip amount is {total:.2f}'` — `total`? =)

Comment: I just fixed it. I just added total amount  too